# A question about Mertens function $M(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(n)$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, mobius-function

The Mertens function is defined as:
$$M(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(n)$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.
The Mertens conjecture states: $|M(n)|\lt\sqrt n$. In 1985 A. M. Odlyzko e H. J. J. te Riele proved the conjecture to be false. There exists a number $m$ with $10^{12}\lt m\lt 10^{65}$ for which the previous inequality doesn't occur.

My question is: the number $m$ is the only number for which this happens or is there an infinite (or finite) set of numbers for which the Mertens conjecture is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many counter-examples. This was proved by Tadej Kotnik and Herman te Riele in 2006, in their article *[The Mertens Conjecture Revisited](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11792086_12)* In: Hess, F., Pauli, S., Pohst, M. (eds) *Algorithmic Number Theory. ANTS 2006*. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 4076. Springer, Berlin

Comment: This appears to be a "link-only" answer.  Please include in your answer sufficient information to answer the question without requiring the link to answer for you.

Comment: The question was not a reference request, but given that link is all you provided, please include a full citation, including the journal and/or publisher, and relevant pages.

Comment: @amWhy It is done.